# What I have to do with my visa rejection because of expulsion interests, and my love relationship

Tags: visa, germany, immigration, marriage, criminal-records

My visa application to study in Germany has been rejected because of an interest in deportation (the national German security authorities reported that in my case there are particularly serious expulsion interests according to § 5 Abs. 4 S. 1 i. V. m. § 54 Abs. 1 Nr. 2 and Nr. 4 AufenthG vorliegen.)

It is only after this rejection I explained in my remonstration letter that the allegations made against me by my home country (3rd-word country) do not correspond to the facts and that I was unfairly sentenced to imprisonment (two years).

The embassy replied to my remonstration by stating that the conviction I passed in my home country was not the subject of the rejection but the serious interest in deportation communicated by the national German security authorities and nothing has changed in this regard, they added that there is another serious expulsion interest according to Section 54 (2) No. 8 AufenthG because I admitted in my remonstration letter that I had additionally provided incorrect information in my application.

I'm aware that I made a notorious error in my visa application by not mentioning my judicial record. It is really hard to write something that you do not admit and has occurred years ago that would ruin your dreams.

I did all my best to get admission to the university and to create a new reality for myself. I don’t want to lose the academic opportunity that would change my life. I want to get ahead and turn that page.

Up to date, I asked for a new visa appointment (I'm always enrolled at the university and I continue paying the fees), I got the judicial rehabilitation from my home country, and I applied for the deletion of my data to the Commission for the Control of INTERPOL’s Files (CCF).

Apart from that, I was engaged to a European woman (not german) before my visa had been rejected (I swear that I did not expect the rejection), we love each other too much, and we have planned (before the rejection) to get married next summer, I somewhat explained to her what was happened to me only after the remonstration rejection. She was sympathetic to me and decided to always stay with me.

The problem for me is that I don’t want her to suffer with me, I mean if I am blacklisted, or I am banned from Schengen, she will be also affected by this ban since she will have to leave Europe to stay with me. She has a myriad of advantages in her country over mine, and I cannot accept downgrading her life standard. Her family doesn’t know my antecedent and they trust me, they believe that I am the right person for her. It is true but at the same time, it is wrong if I bring their daughter into this situation. I cannot accept that.

My questions are:

what do I have to do?

what is your advice regarding my visa, and my relationship?

To what degree my situation will affect my fiancée?

Will the embassy of her country accept our marriage, will they give me a family reunion visa?

How I can bypass this ban?

Comment: I’m slightly confused. Does ‘I had additionally provided incorrect information’ refer to your judicial record or something else?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer.  Omitting important information on an application tends to get you banned from a country.